# Nativescript Render Component after the page has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, wikitude

I am trying to add WikitudeArchitectView to my typescript code, I registered the element to the main.ts typescript file:

```js
var architectView = require("nativescript-wikitudearchitectview");
registerElement("ArchitectView", () => architectView.ArchitectView);
```

in the XML file i have added the ArchitectView element tag:

```html
<StackLayout>

  <ArchitectView urlString="http://10.20.30.79:8888" urlLoaded='urlLoaded' urlLoadError='urlLoadError' urlInvoked='urlInvoked'>
  </ArchitectView>

</StackLayout>
```

when i run the code on my Device i get the error [image]

**So I think i need to find a way to render the  after the page has loaded (maybe using ngOnInit) i dont know how to do this**

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can achieve to render after the page has loaded by using ngAfterViewInit.I am also writing the code for ngOnInit.

Here is the bit of code to help you.

```
import { Component, ElementRef,AfterViewInit, OnInit, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
export class DuesComponent implements OnInit AfterViewInit { }

 ngAfterViewInit() {
 <Write your logic inside this funtion>
 }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

Comment: bu the problem is how can i add HTML code after the page has been loaded?

Comment: You can use the page component of nativescript and add the the required component from your typescript file and attach it to the page component.

Here is the link to add a textview from typescript file:
https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-samples/ui/text-field.html

Comment: You can also use the htmlview of nativescript to archive the same, here is the link to that: 
https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-samples/ui/htmlview.html